# PHP PDO injection inside a class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to understand how to use `PDO` inside a class. I wrote this simple class that hold a `PDO` connection who is passed as a part of the `__construct()` inside another class. The problem is that everytime I try to use the method of the class who need the database connection, I recive an error message that is related to the `PDO`'s built in functions like `prepare()`, `execute()`.The error is `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare()`. How i can solve this problem? I've read about dependency injection but for now it's a little bit confusing on how to apply this pattern to the code when using `PDO`

```
<?php

class Database {

    public function __construct() {

        return $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;", "root", "root");
    }

}

class user {

    public function __construct($db) {

        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function createUser($email, $username, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,username,password) VALUES (?, ?, ? )");
        if ($stmt->execute(array($email, $username, $password))) {
            echo "Account successful created";
        } else {
            echo "Something was wrong during the registration process.";
        }
    }

    public function loginUser($username, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT email,username,password FROM users WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");

        $stmt->execute(array($username, $username));
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            if (password_verify($password, $result->password)) {
                echo "logged";
            } else {
                echo "wrong password";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Username or email does not exist in the database.";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Fix quotes for proper highlight.

Comment: Fix this line return $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;','root','root');

Comment: Quotes fixed, sorry for the typo error!

Comment: You are a passing an instance of  `Database` towards `User`, not an instance of `PDO`. Either create a getter/setter for your database handler in `Database`, e.g `getConnection()` and then u can do `$this->db->getConnection()->prepare` or just get rid of the encapsulation and just pass an instance of `PDO` towards `User`

Comment: @DarkBee can you provide an example please?

Comment: @DarkBee I want to avoid to create more than one `PDO` connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a getter for the actual connection if you want to encapsulate the `PDO` connection in an extra class

```
<?php 
    class Database {
        private $dbh = null;

        public function __construct($user, $pass, $database) {
            $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$database.";", $user, $pass);
        }

        public function getConnection() {
            return $this->dbh;
        }
    }

    class User {
        private $db = null;

        public function __construct($db) {
            $this->db = $db;
        }

        public function createUser($email, $username, $password) {
            $stmt = $this->db->getConnection()->prepare("INSERT INTO users (email,username,password) VALUES (?, ?, ? )");
            if ($stmt->execute(array($email, $username, $password))) {
                echo "Account successful created";
            }else {
                echo "Something was wrong during the registration process.";
            }
        }       
    }

}

$user = new User(new Database('root', 'root', 'testdb'));
```

---

From the comments:

It would be better for your case to just pass an instance of `PDO` towards your classes. This should work:

```
<?php
class user {
    public function __construct(\PDO $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php
    /** Init the one and only DB connection for this request **/
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$database.";", $user, $pass);

   //... Do some stuff
   //....
   $user = new User($dbh);
```

Comment: I've tested the code and work smoothly. Is it also possible to avoid the `getConnection()` in some way?

Comment: When i started writing this code I was using the `User` class by adding a `PDO` dependency inside the construct like this `__construct(PDO $db)`.

Comment: What made you decide to drop that aproach? If you aren't going to add any more login to the class `Database` other than storing the handler you should pass the `PDO` instance like you did before

Comment: If you want to avoid the `getConnection()` part this would mean that you either need to chain every `PDO` method in your `Database` class or let `Database` extend from `PDO`, but then you are back to your start

Comment: @user9741470 your first approach is more explicit.  You know what object and methods you are dealing with.  If I look at the user class above, I have no idea what the database object is.

Comment: @DarkBee I've abandoned the injection in the construct because every time the console said that I didn't pass an instance of `PDO` to the class constructor and this because probably for my ignorance I've passed everytime the `$db` variable into the construct.

Comment: I don't know if you are working with namespaces, but if you do the method signature should be `public function __construct(\PDO $db) {` otherwise `PHP` will look for a `PDO` in the current namespace rather the actual (root) `PDO`

Comment: @DarkBee for now I don't implemented yet the namespaces, so maybe the error is because of this? consider that the `PDO` is implemented inside the `Database` class as showed in the code of this question, so it's in the construct. Do you think that if i modify this implementation like you suggested `public function __construct(\PDO $db)`it will work?

Comment: Yes, i've added some code to the answer to reflect this

Comment: @DarkBee thank you, I was totally unware of this. I'm been using OOP recently, so some concepts are new for me.

Comment: @DarkBee just the last question, I need to init the PDO outside the classes is this right?As i see from your example, it's an instance created outside a class.

Comment: Yes, just place in a file called `db.php` and do a `require_once 'db.php';`  to ensure you only have one connection

Comment: Ok, perfect. Initially I've tried to avoid this approach but if this is the best method I will follow this way.